# React-Native: State is not updating with setState?

Tags: reactjs, react-native

I am trying to change state of "loading" from true to false but when I call a function and inside that function setting "this.setState({loading: false})" still loading state remains true.

In the code below, when buttonPressed function is called it is setting "loading" state to true as expected but when user successfully sign in "loading" state should become false so that my renderButton function will re-render and spinner can hide itself and show button.

**Why "loading" state is not changing to false inside loginSuccess function?**

```js
class Login extends Component {
    constructor(props){
        super(props);
        this.state = {
            name: '',
            email: '',
            password: '',
            errorMessage: '',
            loading: false,
        };
    }
    //after successfully login with email and password
    onLoginSuccess(){
        this.setState({
            email: '',
            password: '',
            errorMessage: '',
        });
        this.setState({loading: false});
        this.props.buttonPress;
    }
    
    // to render either button or spinner
    renderButton(){
        if(this.state.loading){
            return <Spinner />;
        }else{
            return (
                <TouchableOpacity style={styles.button} onPress={this.buttonPressed.bind(this)} >
                    <Text style={styles.buttonText}>{this.props.userAction}</Text>
                </TouchableOpacity>
            );
        }
    }
    
    //setting loading state to true and authenticating user
    buttonPressed(){
        const { name, email, password, loading } = this.state;

        this.setState({errorMessage: '', loading: true});

        if(this.props.userAction==='Login'){
            firebase.auth().signInWithEmailAndPassword(email, password)
                .then(()=>{
                    console.log("sign in");
                    this.onLoginSuccess.bind(this);
                    console.log(this.state.loading); // to get current state at console
                })
                .catch((error) => {
                    let errorCode = error.code;
                    if(errorCode==='auth/user-not-found'){
                        console.log(this.state.errorMessage+' user not found');
                        this.setState({errorMessage: 'authentication failed'});
                    }else if(errorCode==='auth/wrong-password'){
                        console.log(this.state.errorMessage+' wrong password');
                        this.setState({errorMessage: 'authentication failed'});
                    }else{
                        console.log(this.state.errorMessage);
                        this.setState({errorMessage: 'authentication failed'});
                    }
                });
        }
        //User Sign Up
        else{
            firebase.auth().createUserWithEmailAndPassword(email, password);
        }
        
    }

    render(){
        return (
            <View style={styles.container}>
                
                <Input 
                    placeholder="Email" 
                    keyboardType="email-address"
                    value={this.state.email}
                    onChangeText={(email)=> this.setState({email})}
                />
                <Input 
                    placeholder="Password" 
                    keyboardType="default"   
                    secureTextEntry={true}
                    value={this.state.password}
                    onChangeText={(password)=> this.setState({password})}
                />
                {this.renderButton()}
                <Text>{this.state.errorMessage}</Text>
            </View>
        );
    }
}

export default Login;
```

Update-------

This is console output after successful log, there were no output before login

[image]

Comment: can you show to me console.log of state before and after onLoginSuccess?

Comment: Place your `console.log` in `setState` callback to see the updated state, you are logging loading state before the state update here.

Comment: Have you tried to call set state with a function? e.g. `this.setState(() => ({loading:false}));` do this on all `setState` calls. And also why split into 2 calls? why not use the same object and single call?

Comment: @AbidRakhmansyah I have updated the question with console output image. There were no output before login

Comment: @Dyo please elaborate how to place callback in setState?
I tried this setState((prevState)=>{return {loading: false}});

Comment: You can also try to add a callback to setState when the state change is complete: `this.setState(()=>({errorMessage:''}), ()=>{console.log('state changed, do something else');});`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`this.onLoginSuccess.bind(this);` this line won't actually call the function.

Put `this.onLoginSuccess = this.onLoginSuccess.bind(this);` in your constructor and then call the function like this `this.onLoginSuccess()` in firebase auth callback.

Comment: Smallest possible fix is to change `this.onLoginSuccess.bind(this)` to `this.onLoginSuccess.call(this)`. But a larger refactoring is probably justified.

Comment: You are correct but I find it redundant to put bind calls all over the place. Specially when you have to reuse the functions elsewhere. But its a subjective preference.

Answer (score 3):

As Hunaid Hassan said, you're not executing the function doing `this.onLoginSuccess.bind(this)`, you can bind in constructor or use an arrow function to avoid the binding (see below code).

```
onLoginSuccess = () => {
    this.setState({
        email: '',
        password: '',
        errorMessage: '',
        loading: false,
    }, () => { console.log(this.state.loading) }); // callback function to be called after state is updated
    this.props.buttonPress; // this function isn't executed do this.props.buttonPress() instead
}
```

Comment: Why need to call callback function after changing state. I know sometimes after state change component render in batch. Does it force component to render again?

Comment: @Arunkumar all `setState()` calls are async batched or not, so if you need to `console.log()` the updated state you can do it this way, you can't rely on `this.state` result after calling `setState()`

Comment: @Arunkumar Btw it does a re-render only in case you call `setState()` again in the callback.

Answer (score 2):

On top of @Hunaid-Hassan answer:

```
onLoginSuccess = () => {//making it arrow will let you avoid using bind
    this.setState(() => ({
        email: '',
        password: '',
        errorMessage: '',
        loading: false
    }));
    this.props.buttonPress;//<-what is it? do you meant to call it? this.props.buttonPress();
}
```